# Incorrect text indentation following floating image tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple box with a centralised image, followed by a heading and text.  Like this:

[image: example]

```css
.service-box {
  height: 240px;
  width: 360px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -56px;
  left: 124px;
}

.service-box-text {
  border: solid 1px hotpink;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 182px;
  padding: 80px 32px 32px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112">
  <div class="service-box-text">
    <h5>HEADING</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can achieve this applying a float to the image, but then the following text is incorrectly indented (it should be centered in the image).

[image]

It should be simple but I cannot figure out how to get the heading centered correctly.

How can I fix this issue, or am I going about it in the wrong way?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x76v0a8k/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your float on the next element. Once you do that, it works just fine.

```
 .service-box-text {
    border: solid 1px hotpink;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 182px;
    padding: 80px 32px 32px 32px;
    clear: left;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x76v0a8k/3/

Absolute positioning will also work, but it's not always easy to work with on responsive pages.

Comment: This works, but it also pushes the whole box down by about 60px - not sure why that is (you can compare the two JS Fiddles to see)

Comment: This is because your first positioned element is the placeholder image, and it has a relative positioning from the top with a value of 56px. If you want to remove that space, then remove the positioning properties from the image and apply them instead to the div with the class of service-box-text. When applied to the div, the value should be "-56px" to create the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of floating and relative positioning, you can use absolute positioning:

```css
.service-box {
  height: 240px;
  width: 360px;
  margin-top: 28px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.service-box-text {
  border: solid 1px hotpink;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 182px;
  padding: 80px 32px 32px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112">
  <div class="service-box-text">
    <h5>HEADING</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was the simplest solution but I found it didn't work in IE11.  Josh's answer does work in the browsers I've tested.

Answer (score 1):

Using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) inside a single container can be achieved.

```css
.service-box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.service-box img{
  transform: translateY(-50px) rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%
  max-width: 112px;
}
.service-box h5{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="service-box">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/112x112">
   <h5>HEADING</h5>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</p>
</div>
```